# Chrome Extensions or Windows 7 alerts?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, alert

I'm wondering if there are any free Google Chrome extensions or software compatible with Windows 7 that allows the user to schedule time-based alerts with an added note?

For example, I'd be able to set an alert to pop-up from my task bar at 3:00pm with a note saying "Post a forum thread."

I've failed yet to find any for Chrome so far, however I'd love to throw the question out for any answers.

Comment: What is the relevance of Google Chrome?

Comment: I use Chrome as my primary browser.

Comment: Install Google Talk, and put events on your Google Calendar, and setup notifications to your Google Talk client?  This may work as well if leave Chrome running, logged into your gmail account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has "[Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task)" for such things.

In Windows 7 there's a specific task Action for displaying a message on-screen.  It won't pop up from the tray, but instead show a window with your chosen title and text.  Also, it's free and included already. ;)